# Where should I store user subscription history in Firestore, inside or outside the user collection?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a flutter application, where we uses firestore for database, Now I have a user collection that have parameters like id, name , email ,photourl , And I also want the user subscription history like plan , payment id , start date and end date. Now My question is that, We should be subscription collection inside the user collection or outside the user collection. Which one is good.

Which one is better option

Comment: **There is no "better" option**; store the data wherever makes the most sense for the App. Firestore is not sensitive to the number of collections or even where they are located. Collection placement depends on the kinds of queries being run against it. That data could be stored along with each user if it needs to be loaded when the other user data is loaded, or it could be stored in a separate collection if other queries are needed. Try something and see if it works. If you get stuck with a coding issue, post it and we'll take a look.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to reduce the number of collections in the firestore. Less collections in the firestore that's the best. Try to do the subscription collection inside the user collection that makes the firestore structure more efficient.

Comment: Firestore doesn't care how many collections there are - the location of data in Firestore is dependent on the queries being run. The number of collections and documents does not make Firestore any more or less efficient.